# excel dynamic drop down list based on user input from 1 to n to x

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

I have created a drop-down list in Excel based on a named range of numbers from 1 to 500. What I can't figure out is how to force the number that appears first on the drop-down list to be based on a user input number in another cell (n), and then for the drop-down list to allow the user to scroll either down from n to 1 or up from n to 500. Currently my drop-down list always starts with 1. Formula or VBA would be fine.

I've attached a screenshot of the Excel file I'm referencing. Cell B12 has data validation from a named range in column CD, which are numbers from 1 to 500. The user inputs a number in cell H4, which populates in cell B12. I want the drop down list to start with this number, currently 200, and allow the user to scroll up or down from there. Currently the drop-down list will only start with 1.

Thank you very much!

#### screenshot of the excel file

[image: screenshot of the excel file]

Comment: can you provide some code or screenshots?

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the question. Maybe you have some sample data or even a mock-up to illustrate what you want to achieve?

Comment: screenshot and explanation added

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding what you are trying to do. As I understand it the user puts a value in H4 between 1 and 500. Whatever value the user puts in you want the corresponding drop down to start at the equivalent value, but still have access to the full range 1-500.

Assuming I have understood what you are trying to do then what is needed is accomplished by a VBA macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H4")) Is Nothing Then
  Range("B12").value = Range("H4").value
  End If

End Sub
```

This macro is applied directly to the sheet instead of a module. Go to your Developer Tab, click view code. In the project window that opens up double click the worksheet to open and activate the code window specific to that sheet. Make sure to place the code there.

I tested this out and verified that when you change the value in H4 B12 also changes and the scrolling for the drop down starts at that number.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I added this code to the worksheet window but the scrolling still starts at 1 and not the user input number.